# Entity based security in asp.net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, security, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been finding some solution to put security on basis of entity.Like a user can only access to entity to which it has access.

Rather than putting check on each and every action method can i control in centralized way. I am here talking about access entity using ajax call also. For example a user has opened a orderId 10 for that i have an hidden   field if by any means if he changes the value of orderId to 11 he can access or modify order with orderId 11 while he was allowed to see only orderId 10 .

There are the time we just send some values along with main entity id for example getOrderByUserId(int userId) as this action method is in OrderController accessing order based on userId.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take look at [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and the roles in specific

usage :

```
[Authorize(Roles = "manager,admin")]
public ActionResult myMethod(){

 // your code
}
```

And you can use the `Users` property and do something like this:

```
[Authorize(Users = UsersHelper.GetAllowedUsers)]
public ActionResult myMethod(){

 // your code
}
```

where `UsersHelper.GetAllowedUsers` is a static class with a static method that returns users in format like this : `"joe1,admin,momandpop"`

update to OP comment :

```
/// <summary>
/// Checks if the current user is the owner of the Order
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class IsOwnerOfOrderAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (!(filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult))
        {
           // code to check if user has the order he is trying to edit
           // if not return this
           filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

you can place this on top of a controller or a specific action.

Comment: GetAllowedUsers, nice +1

Comment: But i was expecting a more generic solution i.e. some thing can fetch userID, as it knows it's an user on basis of (user)(Id) and authenticate.Better example will be of getOrderByProductId(int productId). This is the case when we are displaying some order on basis on product but i want to restrict user such that it can't change order entity if user changes hidden field of my view which contains orderId.Putting authorize on each and every action method is not appealing what about using fluentSecurity.

Comment: then you need to keep a list of each order for every user, and if the user  doesn't have that order ID he is denied access. sample to follow

Comment: Thanks waiting for the sample

Comment: it's there  under "udpate to OP comment"

Answer (score 0):

you are not talking about entity based security but row-wise security as provided by mssql.
Entity Based security is if a user is allowed to edit, he will be able to edit any other id.

For this you have to maintain hierarchy of user roles and then storing the minimum role that can perform edit or any action on each row in the table.

Or if you want to block user from using query parameter, you can use parameter or session or TempData to transfer data between actions to transfer id and work.

Comment: I am bit unclear what you are suggesting here . I have a simple requirement that no user can change data of an entity which he is not allowed to, it can be on basis of custom rules like what permission he has . I dont want to put check on every action method.

Comment: To Write Validate codes on only once, create a BaseController that will check the required validations in the function as `   protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {'and the controller that needs to validate this will extend this base controller.

Comment: this will check on every action executing event of controller that extends it, but as per your question you need to perform a check on each row... of data from table.